# How do I sort a Dictionary by its values?

Tags: sorting

My data looks like this:

```
var dict = {12543 : "Smith, David(12543)",
            48392 : "Rogers, Jim(48392 )",
            26788 : "Everton, Mike(26788)"};
```

Comment: You can change it to an array with all the elements, which is easy to sort.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that??? and then put it back to a Dict

Comment: I am trying to take a Dic and sort it in an array, sort it, and put it back into a Dic, but it will not keep the sort on the name? Can this be done, if so, how?